# using REPLACE INTO for both new items and edited items?

Tags: php, mysql, refactoring, pdo

This refactor seems workable in my head, but I'd like someone to check my logic:

Current process:

```
if (item == new) {
    INSERT INTO basic_table
    $itemUID = get last insert ID // item's UID
    INSERT INTO another_table // more stuff
    INSERT INTO another_table2 // more stuff
    INSERT INTO another_table3 // more stuff
} else {
    $itemUID = $_POST['uid']
    UPDATE basic_table
    REPLACE INTO another_table // more stuff
    REPLACE INTO another_table2 // more stuff
    REPLACE INTO another_table3 // more stuff
}
```

*(note -  **REPLACE INTO** is used for existing items because they may or may not have entries in all the tables, depending on their initial configuration)*

It occurred to me that since all the follow-on queries are identical except for `INSERT INTO // REPLACE INTO`, I should be able to refactor as:

```
if (item == new) {
    INSERT INTO basic_table
    $itemUID = get last insert ID // item's UID
} else {
    $itemUID = $_POST['uid']
    UPDATE basic_table
}
    REPLACE INTO another_table // more stuff
    REPLACE INTO another_table2 // more stuff
    REPLACE INTO another_table3 // more stuff
```

Considering that I'm using PDO and each of those queries has lots of parameters, this would save a *crapload* of space.

But I wanted to post it here first, to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Would this refactoring produce the same result?

Comment: Why don't you just use `REPLACE` for all four?

Comment: Have a look at INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the primary key changing, use `REPLACE`. If the key needs to remain consistent, as in, if it has been mapped to other tables, continue to use `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. `REPLACE` deletes and re-inserts so if your primary key is an `auto_increment` field it will change to the new increment value.